# How to make balls fall in Blender without passing through each other?

Tags: modeling, animation, physics, soft-body

I am trying to make an animation to look like this.  Do you have any suggestions on how i can make many balls like this fall down on to each other?  I do not want them to pass through each other and want to stack each ball on itself.  I've attached an example of what I am trying to achieve.

https://www.storyblocks.com/video/stock/pile-of-gumballs-fill-screen-with-colorful-rolling-and-falling-balls-multicolored-spheres-in-pool-for-children-fun-abstract-transition-bright-3d-animation-for-composite-overlay-with-alpha-channel-skp37c9urk1ifyxc6

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Sanbaldo says. If you're still having problems, you might need to increase the "steps per second" in the scene properties tab > Rigid body world.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the balls as "Rigid Body - Active". The box should be "Rigid Body - Passive" (remove unwanted faces and recalculate normal internally, hide from render).

Animate and it should simply work.

check this file:
https://pasteall.org/blend/2097ed28b4cc4f77a15206e01ede3cf7